# stockage in structure and iteration

Tags: matlab, iteration, structure, stock

I would like to understand one thing :

When I write : Propreties.Device.Time = Data.Device(lobo(:,2),1) - Data.Device(lobo(:,1),1) I obtain a stockage of all the differencies (it's great)

But when I write : Propreties.Device.Prop = sum(Data.Device(lobo(:,1) : lobo(:,2)),2)*dt I don't obtain a stockage of all results (that I would like to obtain as previous exemple) but an overwrite of each of them so at the end I have only one value :-/

Could someone explain to me what differs between the two examples and what I could implement to obtain in the second example the same type of result as in the first (ie a list of results and not a single result) (without making a loop) ?

(Matlab verison : R2017a)

*Some data for exemple* :

```
Data.Device = [1.86000000000000 675 0;1.87000000000000 685 0;1.88000000000000 695 0;1.89000000000000 705 0;1.90000000000000 710 5;1.91000000000000 715 50;1.92000000000000 700 120;1.93000000000000 685 180;1.94000000000000 655 235;1.95000000000000 620 285;1.96000000000000 565 305;1.97000000000000 505 315;1.98000000000000 435 335;1.99000000000000 360 345;2 285 355];



lobo = [1 5; 6 15];

 dt = 0.01

Propreties.Device.Time = Data.Device(lobo(:,2),1) - Data.Device(lobo(:,1),1);
 Propreties.Device.Prop = sum(Data.Device(lobo(:,1) : lobo(:,2)),2)*dt
```

Comment: What are you expecting in `Propreties.Device.Prop`? You are summing some data, that is why the output is a single value.

Comment: I would like to have in this case two values because I have two index sets for Data.Device

Comment: Maybe you are looking for this: `Propreties.Device.Prop = sum(Data.Device(lobo),2)*dt` ?